# Get last file modification date of application data files?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a plist file in my application data that i want to update from a webserver every 24 hours. Is there a way to check when the file is last modified or should i, in some way register the date and time when i update the file, and use that to compare to?

```
if (lastMod > currentDate){
    [arrayFromXml writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use NSFileManager for this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:@"path/to/my/file" error:nil];

NSDate *date = [attributes fileModificationDate];

// compare 'date'
// date > now
if ([date compareTo:[NSDate date]] == 1) 
{
    [arrayFromXML writeToFile:@"path/to/my/file" atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: `error:` is an `NSError **`. If you don't need it, you should pass in `NULL`, not `nil`.

Comment: @H2Co3 I suppose if you're being pedantic, yes. Although I highly doubt that anyone in practice will be confused.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII AFAIK `nil` and `NULL` expands to the same on iOS, it's the concept that differs.

Comment: @H2CO3 that was my point - they are (mostly) equivalent, so I use them interchangeably for the most part. If you're this deep into objc and you don't understand that they are the same, you have larger issues.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Yes, I know, I was just confirming what you wrote :) And I do understand that they're the same.

Comment: @H2CO3 so it's clear - I wasn't talking about you specifically, but a future third party. I trust that you of all people has a very firm grasp on objc ;)

Comment: `[attributes fileModificationDate]`? Since when has an `NSDictionary` method `fileModificationDate`?

Comment: @RudolfAdamkovic it is an IO extension on NSDictionary: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/fileModificationDate

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Ah, didn't know that! Sorry then, and thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score -3):

you can store the `NSDate` in `NSUserDefaults` when saving..and then compare it with current time to check the difference,,