# NSFileManager defaultManager how to know a file is open?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsfilemanager

For example:
I have a file in my document named @"CoreSimulator/Devices/.../abc.pdf"

and how do I known this file has been open ever?

Can I add any customer tag into file use NSFileManager? like "lastOpenTime"

Comment: Please follow this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9365425/5649323 This might help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there *is* a way to know the last time a file was opened/accessed. `NSFileManager` **does** have a way to find the last time a file was *modified* though. The NSFileManager Class Reference makes mention of the [`-attributesOfItemAtPath:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/attributesOfItemAtPath:error:) method.

This method returns

> An NSDictionary object that describes the attributes (file, directory, symlink, and so on) of the file specified by path, or nil if an error occurred. The keys in the dictionary are described in [File Attribute Keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/File_Attribute_Keys).

---

**EDIT:** You might find this [answer to a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20302533/3649704) handy. It suggests using [MDItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/MDItemRef/index.html).

Comment: I know this method, but I can not set any customer attributes

Comment: Yes I do, and I know there is an attributed name NSFileModificationDate, but I want to known how can I add customer tag to file or do you have any other way to do that